# What if I mount two drives in the same dir

Tags: linux, mount

What happens if I accidentally mount two storage devices in the same dir? Sometimes when I work with multiple drives and constantly mount and unmount them I can by accident rerun same mount command, changing drive, but not the mount point

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

What is happening under the hood? I can still see what inside `/dev/sdb1/` but not `/dev/sda1`. `lsblk` though shows that both devices are mounted at `/mnt`. If I unmount `/dev/sdb1` the `/dev/sda1` files are back.

So, what happens if I do this, is it harmful, could I wreck my drives, is it safe and why `mount` doesn't bother that `/mnt` is already taken by `/dev/sda1`?

Answer (score 2):

It will not damage anything, all that is happening is that you "see" one drive mounted in the same place as the other and the "topmost" drive (I.e. the one that you actually see) is what gets written to.

When you unmount that drive then the next drive gets seen and now it becomes the one that gets written to.